# C# library for 3D math (rotation)

Tags: library, c#, 3d, math

I am working on a C# project where I need to rotate some vectors. Until now I was using a rather complicated solution using rotation matrices but now I also need support for quaternion rotation (and probably converting from one to the other).

Most libraries I find are made for graphics developments. I don't need to output/render any graphics, though. The XNA and DirectX reference pages show details about Matrix, Vector3 and Quaternion classes which seem to provide all I need. But those seem to be somehow outdated?

I am really not experienced in this field of libraries and I'm not sure if there are any solutions which are more up-to-date or if this does not really matter.
Of course it would be great if there is any library which is more light-weight, too. Since the rotation should be performed in real-time, the library should have a good performance.

Comment: So I had a try on [this XnaGeometry library](http://www.technologicalutopia.com/sourcecode/xnageometry/tableofcontents.htm) which seemed to offer exactly what I needed. But it seems like this is pretty buggy, too, regarding the quaternion rotation. So here I am, looking again for a library.

Comment: Maybe the [Math.NET](https://www.mathdotnet.com/) library has what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [MonoGame Framework](http://www.monogame.net/), which is an open source implementation of the XNA framework. I just added the [MonoGame.Framework.WindowsDX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoGame.Framework.WindowsDX/) package to my project which offered the same namespaces as [Microsoft's XNA documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203940.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). So I could easily have `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;` in my classes to use `Quaternion`, `Matrix` and `Vector3` objects.

For me, this seems to be a good solution, if you don't need any gaming, graphics or rendering features. You can just add the NuGet package and use the XNA classes you need.

Answer (score 0):

The more obvious choice might have been to use [System.Numerics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics?view=net-5.0). Alternatively at my company we developed an open-source library [Vim.Math3d](https://github.com/vimaec/Math3D) from System.Numerics combined with many useful algorithms and structures from MonoGame. For completeness we are maintaining a [list of similar 3D Math libraries](https://vimaec.github.io/Math3D/articles/csharp-math-libraries.html).